# What is the distribution of a parameter which is expressed as a difference between constant and a Gamma distribution?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, gamma-distribution

I have a variable $x_0$ which is an initial value of a process, it is a constant. The change in the process $\Delta x_t$ follows a Gamma distribution with parameter $(\alpha_t, \beta)$. What will be the distribution of new variable $x_t=x_0-\Delta x_t$? What will be the parameters of the distribution of $x_t$?

Comment: Umm ... the parameters will be exactly what you stated: $\alpha_t, \beta, x_0$.  It's hard to guess what you're looking for in an answer.  Could you expand on the question a little?

Comment: @whuber if  $x_t$= $x_0$-$\Delta x_t$ what will be distribution of $x_t$, given $\Delta x_t$ has a gamma distribution and $x_0$ is a constant?

Comment: That is a perfectly clear description of the distribution, leaving nothing to be desired.  What alternative description do you seek?

Comment: The density can be written down by inspection. Are you after a *name* for it? I don't think there is one, though you might call it a "shifted reversed Gamma", for example.